# Issue in xsl stylesheet when creating pdf using apache fop

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want to convert html document to pdf using Apache FOP. I tried https://blogs.oracle.com/chrisf/entry/converting_html_to_pdf_using worked fine for a basic html file.
but when the page has a right align paragraph this wont work

```
  <p style= "font-size: 10px; margin: 5px 0px 20px; line-height: 130%; border-radius: 5px;  padding:
            0px 20px 0px 0px; float: right">
                Invoice No : $invoiceId  <br>
                Date : $date  <br>
                Client Ref : $customerAccount  <br>
                Email : $email
            </p>
            <br> <br> <br> <br> <br/>
```

I tried to create a simple xsl file but getting the below error

```
(Location of error unknown)org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: First element must be the fo:root formatting object. Found (Namespace URI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", Local Name: "html") instead. Please make sure you're producing a valid XSL-FO document.
```

Please find the xsl file I created.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="html">
            <xsl:attribute name="xmlns">http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="head">
                <xsl:element name="meta">
                    <xsl:attribute name="equiv">content-type</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="content">text/html;charset=utf-8</xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="title">
                    Happy
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="body">
                <p style= "font-size: 10px;margin: 5px 0px 20px; padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px; line-height: 130%;
                                  max-width: 258px;">
                    <b>Accounts Payable</b><br/>
                    $Description <br/>
                    $address_line1 $address_line2<br/>
                    $address_city, $address_state $address_zip <br/>
                    $address_country <br/>
                </p>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your XSLT is generating an XHTML 1.0 document, which is a completely different vocabulary to the elements and attributes that you use for XSL-FO.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way of doing this? I'm kinda new to the xsl and xsl-fo. As I understand issue is in the "stylesheet xsl file" for HTML to XML/XHTML translation. Step 2 in the tutorial

Comment: that xsl file wont help when I have <p style= "float: right"> . I want the text to be right side of the page